# Start an activity and close it without ui change

Tags: android

I really need to start an activity and close it without ui change, I thought about a transparent screen, is this the best solution? any better ones?

I really need an activity because of the task affinity

Comment: If you could tell us why, we could help more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need UI, you're probably looking for a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: It's a little bit more complex, I need an activity cause it can have a different task affinity, and a service or a BroadastReciever can't

Comment: I repeat: What are you trying to do in that Activity?

Comment: If it's just a simple operation start, execute and close...why do you need task affinity? This is basically to define the way the activities get stacked...i don't see why it should be relavant in this case.